# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. poweshell

Tags: powershell

just found a sctipt that conver json to csv. I'm getting error Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

```
$pathToJsonFile=C:\Users\ritsharma\Desktop\employees.json
$pathToOutputFile=C:\Users\ritsharma\Desktop\employees.csv
((Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile) | ConvertFrom-Json).results |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

Here is the json file

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
 ]}
```

Comment: can you share an example of the json you are importing.

Comment: just updated the json file

Comment: So correct me if Im wrong, what you want to do is export the employees in the array of employees to a CSV file?

Comment: my motive is to covert json files to csv files. i got it code online and trying to make it work

Comment: If the json files are have a flat structure that is possible to do without flattening the json first. If is a depth structure then you cant convert it to csv file since csv files are by nature a flat file type. In this case your json is not flat hence you need to do something with it first. e.g. deciding if you only want to export the rows of the employees to a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your variables values with double quotes.

```
$pathToJsonFile="C:\temp\employees.json"
$pathToOutputFile="C:\temp\employees.csv"

(Get-Content -Path $pathToJsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json).employees | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content $pathToOutputFile
```

Comment: not getting this error Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.

Comment: @ritwiksharma I think you want to do something like this right?